# Python extract text from Struct, or binary file

Tags: python, struct, binary, extract

I'm trying to extract some text from a binary file. There is not much readable in the file other than the text I'm trying to extract. I would attach the file here, but since it's binary it wont make much sense, because it would be unreadable.

I don't know the format of the struct, so I'm guessing there is no way I can unpack it, or is there?

I tried this, but it seems I would need to know the position of the bytes in order for it to work?

```
with open('hello', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(1)
    bytes = f.read(3)
    string = struct.unpack('s', bytes)
    print st
```

I can see the text in the binary file, so I'm sure there must be some sensible way of extracting it?

I tried this, but it came up with errors, saying there is no string to work with

```
import sys
import re
print 'asd'
chars = r"A-Za-z0-9/\-:.,_$%'()[\]<> "
shortest_run = 4

regexp = '[%s]{%d,}' % (chars, shortest_run)
pattern = re.compile(regexp)

def process(stream):
    f = open(stream, 'rb')    
    data = f.read()
    return pattern.findall(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for found_str in process(sys.stdin):
        print found_str


process("c:/mytextfile")
```

There is padding on either side, so maybe I can use that to extract the text?

I'm wondering what is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: The first step in the best approach is to figure out what code *created* this binary data. Once you know that, you can track down documentation or maybe examine the code itself to figure out the specifications of the data format. (If you have to examine the code, documenting the format would probably be a good idea.) If those aren't an option, you're in reverse engineering territory.

Comment: you dont know the structure but you want to decode that? you might want to use xxd or some hex editor to see the offset and then find the rules, generally, most serialized data got header or length, and checksome, just guess and apply, to see if you could get aligned split messages

Comment: Could you please copy paste the errors text

Comment: I think Jack Wu gave the answer I was looking for. If you give this as an aswer I'll gladly accept it. I need to find the offset of the data and then work from there on how to extract it. Would be grateful if you have any tips with regard to determining whether offsets have some logic to them (like + x bytes to next offset) etc